# imageView in UITableView cell violates setClipsToBounds on touchdown event

Tags: uitableview, imageview, contentmode

I have a `UITableView` whose cells have an image from a URL placed in its `imageView`.

The image isn't square (is landscape), however it initially loads as a square in the manner in which `contentMode` is `scaleAspectFill` and `setClipsToBounds` is `YES`. So far so good.

However, when I touch down on the cell, the image "widens", that is, it retains the `scaleAspect` part, but now bleeds out to the right as if `setClipsToBounds` is `NO`.

The same behavior occurs if the row/cell goes out of view and comes back in recycled, in which case I have the image obtained from an in-memory cache rather than from the URL.

I've tried explicitly setting both `contentMode` and `setClipsToBounds` for the `cell.imageView`, but it seems to have no effect. Any advise? Thanks.

Before touchdown:

[image: before touchdown]

After touchdown (or recycle from cache):

[image: after touchdown]

Answer (score 0):

`imageView` cell property (same as other `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel`) changes its  frame in `layoutSubviews` accordingly to image size. So you can reimplement `layoutSubviews` to have fixed frame rect. BTW, try [TableKit](https://github.com/onegray/UITableKit) library.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean I have to subclass UITableViewCell, work with cells of that type, and override that class's layoutSubviews?

Comment: First, you need to disclose your authorship when promoting a project you wrote.  The same rules apply as when you're promoting a product or website of your own (see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) for details).  Second, you should explain *why* someone should try it.  Example code showing how it solves the problem in the question would do that.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a link to the correct answer if anyone is still looking for a solution: [UIImageView in UITableViewCell changes size on touchDown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17123367/3543861)

Its because you named it imageView, name it something like image_View and the problem is solved!